# session invalidate not working in java

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlet-filters

I have a filter namely UserFilter in front of all requests. It will verify there is a user attribute in the session and then let them go to further pages/servlet. Also in all the pages we have a logout button which will call logout servlet where I wrote the below code.

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

But after clicking the logout also if I type any servlet url directly it goes. (i.e) it is not getting redirected to login page. But I noticed, it went to the filter but inside the filter it is able to retrive the session attribute EPORTALUATUSER. See the code below.

```
String userLogin = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("EPORTALUATUSER");
```

But inside the logout servlet after the session invalidate if I retrive the attribute I am getting null response.

Please advice what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `p1` is a jsp `(p1.jsp)` page or a servlet `url`?

Comment: P1 is a servlet. Which will redirect to jsp pages based on session variables.

Comment: What did you check in a P1 servlet to restrict user? If you invalidate the session, than on the next request it will create a new session, so make sure you are not only checking if session is exist or not.

Comment: Can you put a whole code snippet for logout and filters?

Comment: Try disabling caching in the jsp